# Rails 5.1.2 ransack includes how to add deep associoations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have following models and i wish search Order model with criteria related to  models Department Supplier

Question is  how to includes other models  Supplier and Department in this code

```
@q = Order.ransack(params[:q])
@objednavky = @q.result.includes(:user,:food).page(params[:page])
```

Definitions of models

```
class Supplier < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :food
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :department
  has_many :orders
end

class Department < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end

class Food < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :supplier
  has_many :order 
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :food
end
```

Comment: @Pardeep thanks for edit

Comment: This indeed isn't mentioned in Ransack's [documentation on associations](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#associations). What query are you trying to do exactly? Did you try e.g. `q[food_supplier_name]=x`? Also, depending on your query, you may run into [issue #374](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/374).

Comment: I'm still having this issue, anybody have a clue ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and could not find the answer anywhere. Eventually figured out the following:

```
  private def search_includes
    [
      user: :department,
      food: :supplier
    ]
  end
  @objednavky = @q.result.includes(search_includes).page(params[:page])
```

If the association is deeper I believe you can nest by doing something like:

```
  private def search_includes
    [
      user: :department,
      food: [supplier: :another_assoc]
    ]
  end
```

Hope this helps others and apologies if this is not what you are asking.